# React event.preventDefault() from onChange submission does not prevent refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a range form where it sends the changed data to Flask backend on any change so it's seamless. Similar to how openCV trackbar works.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const SlideBarFg = (props) => {
  const [slideLowHue, setSlideLowHue] = useState('');

  const handleChangeLowHue = (event) => {
        setSlideLowHue(event.target.value);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.form.requestSubmit();
  };

  return(
  <form method="POST">
  <label htmlFor="lowHue">Lower Hue: {slideLowHue}</label>
            <input
                id = "lowHue"
                type = "range"
                min = {0}
                max = {179}
                step = {1.0}
                defaultValue = {0}
                onChange={handleChangeLowHue}
            />
  </form>
  );
};

export default SlideBarFg;
```

I have also tried adding a `<form onSubmit = {submitHandler}>` and did the `event.preventDefault()` there.

No matter what I tried it still refreshed and it seems not many have had this combination of having to submit onChange and not refresh, at least from what I found.

Comment: Do you realize what submitting a form actually does? (calling `requestSubmit()`)

Comment: @RandyCasburn The same thing as pressing the submit button I think. That is why I tried to add ```onSubmit``` to the form and handle it that way.
 I probably should mention started learning React for just two weeks now.

What would be the proper way to do what I described if what I am trying here is a dead-end?

Comment: Whenever a form is submitted, regardless of the method of submitting it, it will redirect based upon [these attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attributes_for_form_submission). So you cannot use a form if you want to stay on the same page - this is what [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) is all about.

Comment: Thanks at least I am not wasting more time like this.
Just to be sure I am not going in the wrong direction. Making a async function of my own should do it?

Comment: no, not an Async function, you need to make an async request to your server. That will likely end up in an Async function, but the focus is on making the async request. You'll see in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options) where the `fetch()` API is used (inside that async function) to send data to a server -just like you want to do.

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, I'm just bad with words.
If I figure it out I will add an answer explaining the steps.

First thing I can say is that I needed ```npm i regenerator-runtime``` to even use Async.

Anyway thanks a lot Randy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RandyCasburn

```
import { useState } from "react";

const SlideBarFg = (props) => {
  const [slideLowHue, setSlideLowHue] = useState(0);

const updateFg = () => {
        const specs = {lowHue: slideLowHue, upperHue: slideUpperHue,
                       lowSat: slideLowSat, upperSat: slideUpperSat,
                       lowBright: slideLowBright, upperBright: slideUpperBright};
        console.log(specs);
        
        props.onUpdateForeGround(specs);
    }
  const handleChangeLowHue = (event) => {
        setSlideLowHue(event.target.value);
        updateFg();
  };

  return(
  <form method="POST">
  <label htmlFor="lowHue">Lower Hue: {slideLowHue}</label>
            <input
                id = "lowHue"
                type = "range"
                min = {0}
                max = {179}
                step = {1.0}
                defaultValue = {0}
                onChange={handleChangeLowHue}
            />
  </form>
  );
};

export default SlideBarFg;
```

And in another file:

```
import SlideBarFg from "./SlideBarFg";
import regeneratorRuntime from "regenerator-runtime";

async function updateForeGroundHandler(specs){
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/d_object/capture/fg_specs/',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(specs),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
  })
}
```

And following is the python file:

```py
from flask import request, jsonify

@d_object_blueprint.route('/capture/fg_specs/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def fg_specs_request():
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    return(data)
```

Also at least in my cases I had to do the following:

```py
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to write your own function for sending the data to your backend, and call that instead of `requestSubmit()`.

`preventDefault()` is preventing `requestSubmit()`, which you're then calling manually.  That's whats causing the behavior you're trying to prevent :)

Your function will need to have some kind of AJAX call in it that sends the data to the correct endpoint in your flask API, and then handles the response however you need.

Comment: Well thanks. This isn't exactly good news since at this moment I am not sure how to do that.
So what I'm trying here is not salvageable and there is no "easy" way to do it like how I tried to?

Comment: `preventDefault()` is **not** preventing requestSubmit(), it is prevent the default behavior of the `change` event which is referenced the variable `event` - `event.preventDefault()` is about the `change` event.

Comment: Ah good point, I didn't look close enough and assumed it was on `onSubmit` for the form. The point still applies though, calling `requestSubmit` is going to cause the form to be submitted in the default way, but you'll want to handle it yourself in this case